# Getting error in a try, else statement. (python)

Tags: python, try-catch

I have this code:

```
with gui.Download:
if gui.is_running:  
    try: 
        dialog = str( QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory() )
    else:
        subprocess.call(['/bin/youtube-dl', gui.url])
```

and whenever I run it I get an error on the else block in the try, else statement. Any ideas?

Error:

```
      File "init.py", line 15
    else:
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: `else` is an optional clause in a `try`...`except`-statement, that is executed if no exception is raised. what you probably are looking for in your case is `except`

Comment: So I need a blank except to use else?

Comment: I want to run that code if the try statement succeeds, hence the else

Comment: yes, you would need a blank (`except: pass`) `except` (if that makes sense in your context).

Answer (score 0):

I just ended up using an if statement instead, works great!

```
if gui.is_running:
    dialog = str( QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory() )
    if dialog == '':
        pass
    else:
        subprocess.call(['/bin/youtube-dl', gui.url])
```

Comment: Now I understand your goal. Maybe `if dialog != '':` and then `subprocess.call(['/bin/youtube-dl', gui.url])` is cleaner.

Comment: `if dialog != '': subprocess.call(['/bin/youtube-dl', gui.url])`